# How to find the spectrum $\sigma_p(P)$

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, spectral-theory

How to find the spectrum $\sigma_p(P)$:

Let $P:H\rightarrow H$ be an orthoprojection, $P\neq 0, P\neq I$.

could you please help

Answer (score 2):

Let $H_0=\mathrm{Im}(P)$ and $H_1=\mathrm{Ker}(P)$. Since $P\neq 0, I$, so
$$
\mathrm{Ker}(P)=H_1\neq\{0\}\qquad\mathrm{Ker}(P-\lambda 1_H)=H_0\neq\{0\}
$$
which gives $\{0,1\}\subset\sigma_p(P)$. If $\lambda\notin\{0,1\}$, then consider
$$
R=(1-\lambda)^{-1}P-\lambda^{-1}(1_H-P)
$$
We have
$$
\begin{align}
(P-\lambda 1_H)R&=(P-\lambda 1_H)((1-\lambda)^{-1}P-\lambda^{-1}(1_H-P))\\
&=(1-\lambda)^{-1}P^2-\lambda P(1_H-P)-\lambda(1-\lambda)^{-1}P+(1_H-P)\\
&=(1-\lambda)^{-1}P-\lambda P+\lambda P^2-\lambda(1-\lambda)^{-1}P+(1_H-P)\\
&=(1-\lambda)^{-1}P-\lambda(1-\lambda)^{-1}P-\lambda P+\lambda P+(1_H-P)\\
&=1_H\\
\end{align}
$$
$$
\begin{align}
R(P-\lambda 1_H)&=((1-\lambda)^{-1}P-\lambda^{-1}(1_H-P))(P-\lambda 1_H)\\
&=(1-\lambda)^{-1}P^2-\lambda (1_H-P)P-\lambda(1-\lambda)^{-1}P+(1_H-P)\\
&=(1-\lambda)^{-1}P-\lambda P+\lambda P^2-\lambda(1-\lambda)^{-1}P+(1_H-P)\\
&=(1-\lambda)^{-1}P-\lambda(1-\lambda)^{-1}P-\lambda P+\lambda P+(1_H-P)\\
&=1_H\\
\end{align}
$$
This means that for $\lambda\notin\{0,1\}$ operator $P-\lambda 1_H$ is invertible. Thus $\sigma(P)=\sigma_p(P)=\{0,1\}$